# First Python program: pick and display alien characteristics

Tags: python, beginner

This is my first Python program and all it does is print out a description of the specific "Alien Class" that the user inputs.

Looking for tips and pointers and what I can do better and what I am doing well.

```
# Initializing the alien army with different alien classes

alien_army = {
    'rogue': {
        'name': 'rogue',
        'color': 'green',
        'size': 'small',
        'speed': 'fast',
        'damage': 'small'
    },
    'warrior': {
        'name': 'warrior',
        'color': 'blue',
        'size': 'medium',
        'speed': 'average',
        'damage': 'heavy'
    },
    'hunter': {
        'name': 'hunter',
        'color': 'dark green',
        'size': 'average',
        'speed': 'average',
        'damage': 'average'
    }
}

# Adding an Alien class 'Monk' to the alien_army

alien_army['monk'] = {
    'name': 'monk',
    'color': 'light gray',
    'size': 'small',
    'speed': 'quick',
    'damage': 'average'
}

class_names = []
for k, v in alien_army.items():
    class_names.append(k)

# Function that shows the alien that the user typed

def showPickedAlien(a):
    print(f"{a['name'].upper()}'S are {a['color'].title()} in color, {a['size'].lower()} in size, {a['speed'].lower()} in speed and they do a {a['damage'].lower()} amount in damage.")

# While loop flag to run or stop loop

input_enabled = True

# While loop to keep displaying the alien class that the user inputs

while input_enabled:
    user_input = input("Which class do you want to see? ").lower()
    input_alien = alien_army.get(user_input)

    # Checking if user entered a valid alien class name

    if user_input in class_names:
        showPickedAlien(input_alien)
    else:
        print(f"{user_input.upper()} is not a valid alien class name.")

    # Asking user if they want to see another alien class or not

    input_for_quit = input("Do you want to see another class? ").lower()

    # Determining if the user wants the loop to stop or not

    if input_for_quit == 'no' or input_for_quit == 'n':
          print("Goodbye.")
          input_enabled = False
    elif input_for_quit == 'yes' or input_for_quit == 'y':
          input_enabled = True
```

Answer (score 3):

Good job on your first Python program!

You used a **Dictionary** to store all the alien classes. There are many other alternatives to do the same task. The most common one for this kind of problem is **Python Classes** (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp).

You could simply create a **class** called `myArmy` and then create your soldiers as **objects**.

```py
#Create a class called myArmy
class myArmy:

  #Use the __init__() function to assign values for name, color...
  def __init__(self, name, color, size, speed, damage):

    self.name = name
    self.color = color
    self.size = size
    self.speed = speed
    self.damage = damage

#Create your soldiers (Referred to as "Objects" here. The __init__() function is called automatically every time the class is being used to create a new object.
rogue = myArmy('rogue', 'green', 'small', 'fast', 'small')
warrior = myArmy('warrior', 'green', 'medium', 'average', 'heavy')
hunter = myArmy('hunter', 'dark green', 'average', 'average', 'average')

#Access Rogue information for example
print(rogue.name, rogue.color, rogue.size, rogue.speed, rogue.damage)
```

Next step should be to give them attack/defense values and attack speed, and let the user make them battle each other!

Answer (score 2):

- According to the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) widely-accepted style, your function should be named `show_picked_alien`.
- You don't need a `class_names` list, as you can just do `if key in dictionary`
- If it always coincides with the key, you don't need the `name` attribute
- You don't need a `input_enabled` variable: you can just break out of the loop, or better, put that in a function and return
- You should avoid executable code at the top level of your module, for future extensibility (it also always helps having smaller functions). Use a classic: `if __name__ == "__main__": main()`
- It's better if you pick one quote type (single or doubles) and stick with it, within a program (also from PEP8). But don't pick one style "for life" and apply it on projects using other styles.
- Maybe that's pushing it too far, but if your goal is to make a real application, you can transform your attributes, at least speed/size/damage into enums rather than strings (or use string constants). Because later on you will have checks like `if speed == 'average'` and don't want to repeat string literals and have to make them coincide in several places
- I second MarkH's suggestion of making a class (but with a PEP8-compliant name). If you do this, implement `__str__` on it (maybe the same as your current `showPickedAlien` if not too verbose). That will help with your debugging later on.